# Creating a method that decides the vowel harmony of a word

Tags: java, string

```
    public static String vowelHarmony(String input) {

    String[] high = {"e", "i"};
    String[] deep = {"a", "o", "u"};

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.contains(high[i])&&!input.contains(deep[i])){
            return "high";
        }
        else if (input.contains(deep[i])&&!input.contains(high[i])){
            return "deep";
        }
        else if (input.contains(deep[i])&&input.contains(high[i])){
            return "mixed";
        }
    }
    return "you screwed something up";
}
```

I know, I know, vowel harmony doesn't exist in English but for the sake of the example let's pretend that it does. The `high` vowels are 'e' and 'i'. The `deep` vowels are 'a', 'o', and 'u'. All words belong to either the group `high`, `deep` or `mixed`.

For example:

- If a word only has `high` vowels, it is a `high` word (hell, hill, mill, kill, etc.)
- If a word only has `deep` vowels, it is a `deep` word (sword, hold, stool, cool, etc.)
- If a word has vowels from both groups, it is a `mixed` word (mule, mountain, house, choose etc.)

The only thing is, my code doesn't work as it's supposed to. It never displays if a word is `mixed`. If a word even has a single high letter in it, it will be displayed as `high`. What do I need to do to fix it? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Once any of your return statements are hit, the method ends. For example, if `hello` was your word, it would check for `e` and not `a` (the first position on each array), which are both `true`, therefore it will return `high` and not search again. Also, searching using the length of the input over two different length arrays probably isn’t ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with the code as stated:

- Once any condition is met on the first occurrence (that's all it's checking - the *first* occurrence) - you will get your result.
- If your input is longer than either of your letter arrays (and it is), you're going to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The best thing to do in this case is to check the vowel equivalence directly as opposed to relying on arrays to store it.

```
private static boolean hasHighVowel(String input) {
    return input.contains("e") || input.contains("i");
}

private static boolean hasLowVowel(String input) {
    return input.contains("a") || input.contains("o") || input.contains("u");
}
```

Then you can check *that* in your method.  Also take care to not immediately return from the method.

```
 public static String vowelHarmony(String input) {
    String result = "you screwed something up";

    if (hasHighVowel(input)) {
        result = "high";
    }
    if (hasLowVowel(input)) {
        result = "deep";
    }
    if (hasHighVowel(input) && hasLowVowel(input)) {
        result = "mixed";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Error handling cases - such as when a user puts in `null` or an empty string into this method - are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, this is my favorite solution and the most readable. I have no idea how didn't making other methods to check for different types of vowels didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily:

```
    enum Harmony {
        Deep, High, Mixed, Nothing
    }

    public static Harmony vowelHarmony(String input) {
        boolean canBeHigh = false, canBeDeep = false;
        if (input.contains("a") || input.contains("o") || input.contains("u"))
            canBeDeep = true;
        if (input.contains("e") || input.contains("i"))
            canBeHigh = true;
        if (canBeDeep && canBeHigh)
            return Harmony.Mixed;
        if (canBeDeep)
            return Harmony.Deep;
        if (canBeHigh)
            return Harmony.High;
        return Harmony.Nothing;
    }
```

Comment: Three booleans with multi-level conditionals attached to each of them.  It's not exactly *that* straightforward to read.

Comment: This doesn't handle cases of input with no vowels. Why would you use `&&` and then negate each term? `isHigh = input.contains("e") || input.contains("i");` makes much more sense to me.

Comment: I changed it for better view.it doesn't handle the case which is not both of them (not deep and not high). thanks for mention.

Comment: You're still using `&&` instead of `||` but bonus points for using an `enum` instead of string. We're talking about Java, not Perl after all. No need for stringly typed values.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it too. I use Enum only for better representation and clarity.

Comment: As well you should! Personally I hate seeing `/* param must be one of "one", "two", or "three" */ public void stringly(String param);` What's the point? Just define an `enum`!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have done a bit of Jugaad just to make life easy.I know its not a good coding practice though

```
    enum Harmony
    {
        High,Low,Mixed,Screwed
    }
   public static Harmony vowelHarmony(String input) 
   {

        String[] high = {"e", "i"};
        String[] deep = {"a", "o", "u"};
        input=input.replaceAll("[ei]", "1");
        input=input.replaceAll("[aou]", "0");
        input=input.replaceAll("[^01]", "");
        if(input.contains("1") && !input.contains("0"))
            return Harmony.High;
        else if(input.contains("1") && !input.contains("0"))
            return Harmony.Low;
        else if(input.contains("1") && !input.contains("0"))
            return Harmony.Mixed;
        else
            return Harmony.Screwed;
     }
```